# Execute copy and set only if something changed

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, ansible, timezone, provisioning

For Ansible, I have a role that sets the time zone and populates the setting the (Ubuntu) base system,

```
- name: set timezone
  copy: content='Europe/Berlin'
        dest=/etc/timezone
        owner=root
        group=root
        mode=0644
        backup=yes

- name: update timezone
  command: dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

These two commands are executed no matter what. This means that when Ansible is run twice for the same target, one still gets a `changed=2` in the result summary,

```
default                    : ok=41   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Ideally, everything should be `ok` in the second run.

While I'm guessing that the `update timezone` should have some sort of dependency on `set timezone`, I'm not too sure how to best achieve this.

Comment: (For the task shown here, the `timezone` module is probably a good idea to use. Answering with that does not answer the question though...) (On how to suppress unnecessary changes)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do that by using `register` and `when changed`.

By using [register](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables) the result of the `copy` command is saved into a variable. This variable can then be utilized to create a `when` conditional in the *update timezone* task.

Also, make sure to add a line break `\n` at the end of the timezone content, [otherwise Ansible will always perform the copy](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5715).

```
- name: set timezone
  copy: content='Europe/Berlin\n'
        dest=/etc/timezone
        owner=root
        group=root
        mode=0644
        backup=yes
  register: timezone

- name: update timezone
  command: dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
  when: timezone.changed
```

But you could also solve this problem by creating a `handler` for the `dpkg-reconfigure` command [as described here](https://gist.github.com/garethrees/5591027) :

```
tasks:
  - name: Set timezone variables
    copy: content='Europe/Berlin\n'
          dest=/etc/timezone
          owner=root
          group=root
          mode=0644
          backup=yes
    notify:
      - update timezone
handlers:
 - name: update timezone
   command: dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Comment: It appears that `timezone.changed` is always true since the `copy` is unconditional.

Comment: It seems the old issue https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5715. So you must put line break after Europe/Berlin:

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to register a variable for the `copy` play, then check to see whether it has `changed`.

For instance:

```
- name: make a file
  copy: ...
  register: whatever

- name: run a command
  command: ...
  when: whatever.changed
```

Comment: It appears that `timezone.changed` is always true since the `copy` is unconditional.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the Ubuntu version used using systemd features might also be useful:

```
- name: Set timezone
  command: timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Berlin
  changed_when: false
```

Comment: This will always change the timezone and never show "changed"

Answer (score 1):

To set a timezone with Ansible (>=1.6) on Ubuntu use the `locale_gen` command.

```
- name: set timezone
  locale_gen: name=Europe/Berlin state=present
```

Note: `locale_gen` is an extras module that currently ships with Ansible. It *may* be removed in future versions.